# Log4j is not catching exceptions

Tags: java, google-app-engine, exception, logging, log4j

I am using google app engine and I am having trouble with log4j. Basically I am testing my app and the exceptions are being detected by the dashboard, but not log4j. I am using the following:

```
 catch (Exception e) {
       logger.warn("Exception Alert", e);
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Is this the correct way to catch exceptions using Log4j? It works for some exceptions now. But not all. I want to catch a NumberFormatException (empty string) but this is isn't working.

Comment: Please show the log4j properties / configuration if available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's correct but the `logger` should be initialized via `LogFactory.getLog()` and log level should be at least [`WARN`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Level.html#WARN). Also log4j should be on classpath and configured like in this [examples](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/LOGGINGLOG4J/Log4jXmlFormat).

Comment: It works for some exceptions now. But not all. I changed the level to fatal however it is not picking up some errors. For example it didn't pick up my warn and critical level exception from servlet.